# Calculate antenna size with EIRP

Tags: javascript

I wonder how I calculate the size of a C-Band and KU-Band antenna knowing your EIRP:

http://www.satlex.de/en/eirp_values_ku_band.html

http://www.satlex.it/pt/eirp_values_ku_band.html

Calculating with Javascript, because I have the EIRP of 42 dBW, as I find the size of the antenna?

I made this way, but the code is too large, it would be better to use a calculation to achieve this result.

```
if(dbw >= 64){
    return 22;
}else if(dbw >= 63){
    return 24;
}else if(dbw >= 62){
    return 26;
}else if(dbw >= 61){
    return 28;
}else if(dbw >= 60){
    return 30;
}else if(dbw >= 59){
    return 32;
}else if(dbw >= 58){
    return 34;
}else if(dbw >= 57){
    return 36;
}else if(dbw >= 56){
    return 38;
}.................
```

Comment: Well, the formula is there, it's `EIRP = G * P = 10(g/10) * P [W]` all you really need to do is to transform the formula.

Comment: In fact, I could not because I do not know what this data:
G: Antenna gain coefficient? What's the number?
g: Antenna gain [dBi] What is the number?
P: Power [W] What is the number?

Comment: Then the only way is probably what you are doing, but yo can use shortcuts like between 64 and 55 dbw antenna diameter increases by two for each decrease in dbw. Just look for small things like that can make your code much more compact

Comment: Indeed, this way you can shorten a bit the code ...